# Pass URL parameter through General Config file

Tags: users, url, config, member

This may sound a little odd so let me explain what's going on.

In my current setup I have allowed new users to sign up. I want these users to follow this flow:

1. Fill up sign up form and submit
2. Gets redirected to page that warns them of activation email
3. User opens email, clicks on link and is forwarded to his/her profile page

So far I've been able to do this without any problems. However, I would like to be able to welcome the user when the account is activated without using a new template.

In this moment `'activateAccountSuccessPath'` is set to the profile page, let's call it `'members/profile'` I would like to pass a parameter so that I can detect if the account is being activated for the first time and therefore should display a message, e.g.: `'members/profile?activated=true'`. As of now, this isn't possible because it looks for the template with that name, not recognizing that it has parameters.

I would like to use this same feature for other variables such as `'setPasswordSuccessPath'`, which would take you back to the login page, but displaying a message.

If it's impossible to pass arguments this way, how would you recommend going about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured out how to do it but I'd like to get any opinions on this matter.

Right now I've setup a **dummy template** which contains a **redirect** to the URL with the parameter I need. So:

`'activateAccountSuccessPath' => 'members/activated`

And then that template contains:

`{% redirect 'members/profile?activated=true' %}`

This is working great. And I guess it's a clean way to do it from the point of view that each variable in the config file has a different target. But is it "cool" to do a redirect just for that?

Comment: This is how I'd do it for sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Another possiblity is to have a `members/activated` template which does nothing but [include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) the `members/profile` template:

```
{% include 'members/profile.html' with {'activated': true} %}
```

That avoids the html redirect.